# Extra Space Below Footer in Drupal 7

Tags: theming

I'm currently in the process of updating our current site from Drupal 6 to Drupal 7. Between the designer guy and myself, we have been banging our heads trying to figure out where the extra large chunk of space below our footer is coming from. We have added two new regions and three blocks below our main content and when enabling the blocks, the space appears. We have tried everything we can think of. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

The site URL is http://prosifland.webhost.uits.arizona.edu/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This looks more like a css issue than a drupal issue.
I am not sure if you are looking for some drupal hooks to solve this problem. But adding this css will solve the issue.

```
 .region-links-region{
      overflow: hidden;
  }
```

If this does not work, you can try `overflow: hidden !important;`

Comment: Welcome @Joseph. Please mark as accepted if it solved the issue :)

Comment: Not working for me.!